# Calculate weekly repeat users - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

My goal is to calculate weekly repeat users for a fitness app. I define a weekly repeat user as a user who has created their account within the past 7 days and has completed two *actual* workouts in the same 7 day period.

There are a few conditions that constitute an *actual* workout:

1. Workout duration must be between 10 minutes and 2 hours (or 240 minutes). This part I have covered (or at least I do, as of now, before any suggestions on how to solve the second condition are mentioned).
2. If a user starts two workouts in one day, there must be a 30-minute gap between the 1st workout end time and the 2nd workout start time (in order for two workouts to be counted). **This condition would continue for any subsequent number, n, workouts for the remainder of the day (thinking there may need to be some type of recursive CTE involved, but have no idea how to make that happen). So, if they started three workouts in one day, there must be a 30-minute gap between the end time of the 2nd workout and the start time of the 3rd workout (in order for the third workout to be counted).**

Below is the code I wrote to get all the records showing workouts completed on the same date but at different times. However, it shows duplicate pairs. For example, once I have a record for workouts IDs 36 and 37 paired, I don't need another record showing 37 and 36 paired.

```
select 
    w1.workout_id,
    w1.user_id,
    w1.started_at,
    w1.ended_at,
    w2.workout_id,
    w2.started_at,
    w2.ended_at
from workouts w1 
join workouts w2 
on w1.user_id = w2.user_id
and date(w1.started_at) = date(w2.started_at)
and time(w1.started_at) <> time(w2.started_at);
```

Here is a snippet of the SQL results I received using the code above:
[SQL Date and Time Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaGa1.jpg)

**Any idea how I can get rid of the duplicates, ensure a 30-minute gap between workout end times and start times for workouts started on the same day, then count only those records that meet these conditions?**

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and add the missing data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given information, I will try my best to answer your question. I see your question has two parts:

Q1) While joining w1 and w2, get rid of duplicates.

A1) I believe you can do this by modifying the last line of join clause, "and time(w1.started_at) <> time(w2.started_at)" to time(w1.started_at) < time(w2.started_at). This will ensure that workouts at later periods are not mapped to workouts at earlier periods.

Q2) Ensure a 30 minute gap between workout end times and start times on the same day and count total records with both conditions satisfied.

A2) For solving the second part, you have already done a good job by having "and date(w1.started_at) = date(w2.started_at)" in the join clause. I would just write your code in the following way.

```
with rawdata as 
(
select 
    w1.workout_id,
    w1.user_id,
    w1.started_at,
    w1.ended_at,
    w2.workout_id,
    w2.started_at,
    w2.ended_at,
    datediff(minutes, w2.started_at, w1.ended_at) as time_gap
from workouts w1 
join workouts w2 
on w1.user_id = w2.user_id
and date(w1.started_at) = date(w2.started_at)
and time(w1.started_at) < time(w2.started_at)
)

select count(*) from rawdata where time_gap > 30;
```